# mvn -version 'mvn' is not recognised

Tags: windows, maven

I've installed maven on windows 7 using the windows environment IHM with :

> M2_HOME : C:\dev\outils\maven

and

> PATH : %JAVA_HOME\bin;%M2_HOME\bin;...

java -version works fine

> java version "1.8.0_45" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_45-b15) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

but mvn -version is not working : I get the french equivalent to :

> 'mvn' is not recognised as an external or internal command,
>   operableprgram or batch file

which is :

> 'mvn' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un
>   programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

but mvn works :

> C:\Users\jerome>%M2_HOME%\bin\mvn --version

result :

> Apache Maven 3.3.3 ...
>   Maven home: C:\dev\outils\maven Java version: 1.8.0_45,
>   vendor: Oracle Corporation Java home: C:\dev\outils\Java Default
>   locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 7",
>   version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

I've restarted the PC but it doesn't work better. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YOu need to close the % in the path.

PATH : %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;...

instead of

PATH : %JAVA_HOME\bin;%M2_HOME\bin;...

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I didn't se it!